# How to get the values by clicking specific annotations in iOS?

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview

I am having a map view and 2 text boxes in my app.
Both the text boxes display the latitude and longitude.
I have plotted or mapped few annotations in my map view, and when each annotation is clicked, the callout is displayed with the corresponding latitude and longitude value.
I just want to display those latitude and longitude value in my text boxes. 
I tried the following code,

```
latitude_value.text=myAnnotation.title;
longitude_value.text=myAnnotation.subtitle;
```

latitude_value and longitude_value are the text boxes
myAnnotation is the annotation name
title and subtitle contains latitude and longitude values.
Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set latitude_value and longitude_value by this code:

```
float latitude = [myAnnotation coordinate].latitude;
float longitude = [myAnnotation coordinate].longitude;
latitude_value.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",latitude];
longitude_value.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",longitude];
```

Because CLLocationCoordinate2D is a struct, so it has no concept of methods or of getters. The C dot syntax for accessing struct members is the only correct method.

Comment: Actually, my question was if I select any annotation, its coordinates should be displayed in the text boxes.

Comment: Where should I add these coding.

Comment: @chandru  how about put these code in mapview's delegate method:- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view:

Comment: The last added annotation coordinates are getting printed

Comment: @chandru if you put my code in delegate method,don't forget to change "myAnnotation" to "[view annotation]"

Comment: ya. great I got it,Thank u a lot.

Comment: wat is this [view annotation]. Please explain,.

Comment: look at the delegate method,it pass a (MKAnnotationView *)view.The annotation you need here is contain in (MKAnnotationView *)view.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a tag for myAnnotation custom object, if it's a custom give property like

Suppose myAnnotation has below properties,

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subTitle;
@property (readwrite) int tag; // Tag to identify annotation
```

After this when you are adding annotations, suppose you have array aLocations of objects so give a tag like,

```
for(int i=0; i< [aLocations count]; i++)
{
   // Create MyAnnotation object and initialize it, suppose created object  is myAnnotation, now set it's tag
   myAnnotation.tag=i;
}
```

After that you can access tag value in,

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
   MyAnnotation *temp = (MyAnnotation*) view.annotation;
   NSLog(@"%d",temp.tag);
   // and now use 
   [aLocations objectAtIndex:temp.tag]
}
```

Comment: MKAnnotationView contain annotation which it accessed to.